# Nested map creation in golang

Tags: go

I need to create a map as shown below:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {   
   var data = map[string]interface{}{}  
   data["name"] = "User"    
   data["info"] = map[string]string{}   
   data["info"]["email"] = "user@mail.com"  
   fmt.Println(data)
}
```

I am trying to create nested maps, but I am getting an error as shown below:

```
# command-line-arguments./interface.go:9: invalid operation: data["info"]["email"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
```

Please provide solution to fix this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mu is too short answer is current.
But why do you need it in the first place? map is a data structure suitable for search. It may be the right thing to do in your case but It looks a bit odd.

Answer (score 4):

Your `data`:

```
var data = map[string]interface{}{}
```

is a map from `string` to `interface{}` so `data["info"]` is just an `interface{}` until you assert its type as `map[string]string`:

```
data["info"].(map[string]string) // Now you have a map[string]string
```

Once you have a `map[string]string`, you can index it as desired:

```
data["info"].(map[string]string)["email"] = "user@mail.com"
```

https://play.golang.org/p/yuyAN9FRCxc

Answer (score 0):

According to [Golang Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)

> A variable of interface type stores a pair: the concrete value
>   assigned to the variable, and that value's type descriptor. To be more
>   precise, the value is the underlying concrete data item that
>   implements the interface and the type describes the full type of that
>   item

That's why we needs to type assert `map[string]string` to get the underlying value of `map[string]interface{}`

You also might wants to look at this [post](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces)

For an example you can loop on maps they have indexes. But interface act like a wrapper around type T storing the value and its type. They don't have indexes as the error said.